# How can I sort a table content

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

[image]
On the picture you can see that the green lines are group(ed)_by and sort(ed) as the following codes shows:
**controller:**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if(current_user)
      @user_schedules = current_user.schedules
      @user_schedules_date = @user_schedules.group_by { |tables| tables.date }
    end
  end
end
```

**view:**

```
<% @user_schedules_date.sort.each do |date, schedules| %>
  <tr class="thead success">
    <th colspan="4" scope="col"><p><%= date %></p></th>
  </tr>
  <% for schedule in schedules %>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><p><%= schedule.titel %></p></th>
      <td><p><%= schedule.time %></p></td>
      <td><p><%= schedule.location %></p></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

***How can I sort the "time" additionally?***

---

**EDIT:**
*Database:*

```
id;user_id;titel;location;time;date
1;"12";"Test";"Testort";"12:45:00";"01.01.2014"
2;"12";"Test2";"Testort2";"12:30:00";"01.01.2014"
3;"12";"Test3";"Testort3";"13:00:00";"02.01.2014"
```

---

**EDIT2:**
*Database Update:*

```
id;user_id;titel;location;time;date;date_time
1;"12";"Test";"Testort";"12:45:00";"01.01.2014";"2014-01-01 00:00:00"
2;"12";"Test2";"Testort2";"12:30:00";"01.01.2014";"2014-01-01 01:00:00"
3;"12";"Test3";"Testort3";"13:00:00";"02.01.2014";"2014-02-01 00:00:00"
4;"21";"Test4";"Testort4";"Testzeit4";"Testdatum";"2014-03-01 00:00:00"
```

So this works fine.

The html-table looks like this now:
[image]

**Now I have to understand how to seperate the date and time and how to sort the time at the grey lines.**

I dont know how to use the `strftime`-method. You said I should implement it in the model?
I tried this in the schedule-model:

```
def get_date
  return date_time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y");
end
```

I should add the *view-code*:

```
<% @user_schedules_date.sort.each do |date_time, schedules| %>
  <tr class="thead success">
    <th colspan="4" scope="col"><p><%= date_time %></p></th>
  </tr>
  <% for schedule in schedules %>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><p><%= schedule.titel %></p></th>
      <td><p><%= schedule.time %></p></td>
      <td><p><%= schedule.location %></p></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It would be fine if you could help me again.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `time` field is currently a string. This means, simply calling `sort` by the `time` field will **not** do what you want. Instead, it will sort by the alphanumeric ordering. e.g. `1:00 PM` will come before `10:00 AM` because `:` is less than `0`.

To solve this you can do one of two things:

Parse the time when you need to do the sorting, i.e., like so:

```
@user_schedules_date =
  @user_schedules.group_by(&:date)
    .each do |(_, grp)| 
      grp.sort_by! { |row| Time.parse(row.time) }
    end
```

**Or** (and this is what I would recommend). Combine your `date` and `time` into a single field (let's call it `date_time`), with the type of `datetime`. This way, Rails knows to wrap the value it gets from the database in an instance of `DateTime` before giving it to you, and knows to store the value in the database as a `DATETIME` field.

This is great, because then it simplifies your grouping and sorting to just this:

```
@user_schedules_date =
  @user_schedules.order(:date_time)
    .group_by { |sched| sched.date_time.beginning_of_day }
```

And what's more, the ordering (sorting) is done by the database, rather than after we have loaded it into memory for Ruby, which is, in most cases, preferable.

**EDIT (To answer edits in the question)**

- To get the date string back from the `DateTime` instance, you do the following `date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")`.
- And similarly, for the schedule, getting the time string is done as follows: `schedule.date_time.strftime('%T')`.

Comment: Date_Time opportunity looks well. I'll test it soon. Can I seperate the datetime, like this: datetime.time and datetime.date ? I know this from Java and C# and I want to seperate it in the Users Input and table view. Thanks for your good explaination.

Comment: If you want the date and time strings separately, then yes this is possible, using [`DateTime#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) (You should probably define these as methods on the model's presenter).

Comment: Can you explain it more detailed ? I dont understand it atm: `undefined method 'beginning_of_day' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: That means that you haven't set a `date_time` value for a schedule in your list. You can either change `sched.date_time.beginning_of_day` to `sched.date_time.try(:beginning_of_day)` which will group all the schedules without a date_time under one mapping, and stop the error, or you can remove `nil` items before grouping: `@user_schedules.order(:date_time).reject { |sched| sched.date_time.nil? }.group_by { #... as before }`. Or, make sure that you always set a `date_time`. I would recommend the last option.

Comment: Ok I understand it now, but I also need help by the for each loop.(EDIT2 at the question)

Comment: Updated my answer to match the update to the question. Although, looking at your edits, you've added a `date_time` field, but its value doesn't match that of your `date` and `time` fields...

Comment: I solved it this way: `<th colspan="4" scope="col"><p><%= date_time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></p></th>` Thank you for your help.